# Find an item in a list of lists by multiple elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, search

I'm using a web API to get some geographical information, which returns data in the following format:

```
[
    [lat, lon, another_value, more_values...],
    [lat, lon, another_value, more_values...],
    ...
]
```

The first two values in each sublist (the `lat` and `lon` values) can together be considered a unique identifier. I'm making multiple calls to this API to update my data and would like to be able to replace any `lat`/`lon` pairs that already exist with the new values.

My initial thought is to sort the list of lists by both the `lat` and `lon` values and then do a binary search, but while there are plenty of example of how to sort by a single sublist element, I can't work out how to sort by *multiple* list elements. Of course, if anyone has a better way of identifying a sublist by the first two elements, that would be greatly appreciated too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store and query the data as you get it from the API. This way you can just use a tuple (lat, lon) as the key.

```
d = {}
for line in result:
    d[line[0], line[1]] = line[2:]
```

This takes care of both storing and querying in one shot, as long as the data format is fixed.

Comment: I think this is going to be the most elegant approach (and not inefficient either). Also, I don't think you technically need the parentheses around the tuple IIRC.

Comment: @JaredGoguen you're right. fixed the answer, thanks.

Comment: `d = {(line[0], line(1)): line[2:] for line in result}` for a one-line short-cut

Comment: @schwobaseggl `d = {(line[0], line[1]): line[2:] for line in result}` presumably?

Comment: @Mourndark You are right of course. Mixed up my brackets there!

Answer (score 1):

@Yasser Elsayed's answer is pretty good, but if you'd still like to sort the data by latitude then longitude, you should use [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

```
import operator as op

data = [[0.0, 24.6, 13],
        [1.0, 53.3, 8],
        [1.0, 51.1, 12],
        [-1.7, 37.4, 26]] # arbitrary sample data

data = sorted(data, key=op.itemgetter(0, 1))

print data
# [[-1.7, 37.4, 26], [0.0, 24.6, 13], [1.0, 51.1, 12], [1.0, 53.3, 8]]
```

Comment: Very neat! I didn't know about `itemgetter()`. Yasser solves the problem in one step, but +1 for giving me a very useful tool for the future.